# how can collaspe border with div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is my studi case : 
http://codepen.io/darkiron/pen/ZORNEp

I can't make in my exemple, border collasped. 
How i can do this, in this case ?

```
.col-md-4{
border: 1px solid aqua;
/*margin: -1px;*/
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{
  background-color: #333;
}
.panel {
  margin:auto;
}

.panel-body {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
.panel-body .col {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  display: table-cell;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="panel panel-default ">
      <div class="panel-heading">test</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col">
          content 1
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          content 2
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          content 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
.panel-body div:not(:last-child){
    border-right: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The border-collapse property is for use on `table` elements so if you are not using tables you can make elements behave like a `table` through `display: table` or `display: inline-table`.

You can should add`display: table; display:table-row; display:table-cell;` and  `border-collapse: collapse;`

```css
html,body{
 background-color: #333;
}
.panel{
 margin:auto;
    display:table-row;

}
.container{
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
.panel-body{
 padding:0px;
}

.col-md-4{
 
    display: table-cell;
 border: 1px solid aqua;
  
 /*margin: -1px;*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="panel panel-default ">
   <div class="panel-heading">test</div>
   <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     content 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     content 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     content 3
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of this solution work ! 
all border need collasping (panel too)

@Andrey Fedorov I cant have more div.

the best way I can find it negative `margin` !
http://codepen.io/darkiron/pen/ZORNEp